# AWS cli boto 3 equivalent for aws ec2 get-launch-template-data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I just need to have an equivalent to:

```
aws ec2 get-launch-template-data --instance-id i-0d648aXXXXXX9af2
```

but using boto3. Is this possible ?

Comment: It is possible, please read the docs. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_launch_templates

Answer (score 2):

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.get_launch_template_data(InstanceId='i-0d648aXXXXXX9af2')
```

Here is the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#client) for the boto3 EC2 client.

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
data = client.get_launch_template_data(InstanceId='i-0d648aXXXXXX9af2')
```